# App not opened when clicking on message in notification area

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a Worklight app that works with push notifications. I am currently testing on Android and have got the adapter to send a push notification to the app. The problem is: the app only receives it when it is on the foreground. It doesn't receive it if it was on the background and I open it after a message is shown in the notifications area. Neither does the app open when I click on the message inside the notification area.

I have studied the PushNotifications example and it seems like I am doing exactly the same. I cross-checked the permissions etc. in the Android manifest file against those in the example. However, it doesn't seem to work. Below is an excerpt from the log when running the PushNotifications example.

```
10-08 09:58:48.227: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2771): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
10-08 09:58:48.227: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2771): GCM IntentService class: com.PushNotifications.GCMIntentService
10-08 09:58:48.227: V/GCMBaseIntentService(2771): Acquiring wakelock
10-08 09:58:48.237: V/GCMBaseIntentService(2771): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-4
10-08 09:58:48.237: D/GCMIntentService(2771): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:101 :: WLGCMIntentService: Received a message from the GCM server
10-08 09:58:48.237: W/GCMIntentService(2771): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:108 :: Unable to update badge while received push notification, becasue failed to parse badge number null, badge must be an integer number.
10-08 09:58:48.257: V/GCMBaseIntentService(2771): Releasing wakelock
10-08 09:58:48.257: D/GCMIntentService(2771): GCMIntentService.addToIntentQueue in GCMIntentService.java:123 :: WLGCMIntentService: App is not on foreground. Queue the intent for later re-sending when app is back on foreground.
10-08 09:58:48.277: D/push(2771): Push$1.onReceive in Push.java:91 :: Push: Queuing message for dispatch to javascript
10-08 09:58:48.277: D/GCMIntentService(2771): GCMIntentService.onUnhandled in GCMIntentService.java:164 :: WLGCMIntentService: Showing notification for unhandled Message(alert=Hoi-hoi, badge=1, sound=null, payload={"alias":"myPush","custom":"data"})
10-08 09:59:20.837: D/Whitelist(2771): Unlimited access to network resources
10-08 09:59:20.837: I/CordovaLog(2771): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
10-08 09:59:20.837: D/CordovaActivity(2771): Resuming the App
10-08 09:59:20.837: D/CordovaActivity(2771): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
10-08 09:59:20.877: W/EGL_emulation(2771): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-08 09:59:20.907: D/dalvikvm(2771): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 810K, 27% free 4785K/6516K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
10-08 09:59:20.917: D/push(2771): Push.dispatchPending in Push.java:390 :: Dispatching to javascript Message(alert=Hoi-hoi, badge=1, sound=null, payload={"alias":"myPush","custom":"data"})
10-08 09:59:20.917: D/WLClient(2771): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityStarted in WLClient.java:1180 :: on activity started com.PushNotifications.PushNotifications
10-08 09:59:20.917: D/WLClient(2771): WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityResumed in WLClient.java:1169 :: on activity resumed com.PushNotifications.PushNotifications . activity count = 1
```

My one is almost the same, except that the third line from below (D/push(2771): Push.dispatchPending) is missing. It never seems to dispatch the enqueued event to the app.

What may I be missing?

Worklight version is 6.2.0.00-20140922-2259.

Comment: Did you rename the application in res\values\strings.xml after creating it in the Studio?

Comment: Also, ALWAYS mention your Worklight Studio version and build number.

Comment: I've updated the question with version number.
Do you mean the app_name in strings.xml? I haven't changed it. It was copied (I suppose) from Display name I have in app descriptor. It is, however, different than the app id. If you mean wlAppIdTitle, is has a default value of "App ID" (just as the push sample app).

Comment: After some experimenting I concluded it indeed has to do with the app_name and push_notification_title in res/values/strings.xml. I set these to the original name of my project (1st iteration of 10+) and all of a sudden it works correctly. However, this means I am stuck with an old internal name of the app. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: The development team is already investigating a similar report, so my suggestion is to open a PMR in order to receive a fix once it is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update:* This is actually working as expected. Here is the technical explanation:

The `app_name` value in res\values\strings.xml is used internally to create Intent objects. So when the app is closed and the GCMIntentService receives a message, it creates an intent with the action as `<packagename>.<app_name>` and send it to notification service to show the notification in the notifications bar.

This is the intent name as used in AndroidManifest.xml to indicate that app has to be launched on tapping the notification:

```
<activity android:name=".PushNotifications" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="sensor"> 
    ....
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.PushNotifications.PushNotifications.NOTIFICATION"/>  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
    </intent-filter>
```

So now if the `app_name` is changed to any other string, internally the Intent will be created as `com.PushNotifications.<new_name>`.
But the AndroidManifest.xml still has for example `com.PushNotifications.PushNotifications` (in the case of the sample application), so the app is not getting launched as the intent action is different.

To display the application with a different name, follow these steps:

1. In strings.xml, add an additional  new_name_value
2. In AndroidManifest.xml , modify the label with the new string name

   ```
   <application android:label="@string/app_new_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon"> 
   <activity android:name=".PushNotifications" android:label="@string/app_new_name"...
   ```

---

From the comments: it seems that if changing the application name in Android's res\values\strings.xml, the application will not launch after tapping an incoming notification.

The development team is currently investigating a similar report, so my suggestion is to open a PMR in order to have it investigated for your version of Worklight as well.

The only currently available workaround is to change back the application name back to the originally created name for the application,

Or, create a new application but this time with the desired name instead of changing it after the application creation.

Comment: Thanks, Idan, I confirm it works. However, using a UI string from strings.xml (meant to contain user-facing, translated strings, with spaces and any chars allowed) as an identifier for an intent doesn't seem like a very good design choice.

Comment: I'll make sure to pass this to see if there is a better path

Comment: Idan, on a side note: are there plans to support push messaging for BB10 in the near future (next half a year)?

Comment: That's beyond my pay grade to know.