# Worklight 6.2 Android Application not launching on push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am attempting to get push notifications to work on an Android environment app written in Worklight 6.2.  I have gotten the app to receive push notifications, but when I tap on the notification in the status bar, it clears the notification but does not launch the app.

I have looked at the answer here, [IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Not getting Push Notifications when phone/app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581341/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-not-getting-push-notifications-when-phone-app-is-closed), but changing the app_name string back to the original name of the app, as the accepted answer suggests, does not cause the app to launch.  I also tried another one of the comments suggestions to remove embedded spaces from the displayName in the app descriptor, and that also did not work.

I've watched the logcat and do not see any messages to indicate that it failed to find an app to launch.  I was hoping something in there would give me a hint as to what it is looking for, but no luck.

Is there another setting somewhere that has gotten out of sync so that clicking the notification does not launch the app?  I cannot find anything else myself (probably because it doesn't exist).

Thanks

Comment: Can you recreate this with the sample project provided by IBM? If not, can you provide a redacted copy of your app so it could be tested/debugged?

Comment: I am able to recreate the problem with the sample app. If I change the app_name in the strings.xml file, it fails to launch the app when tapping on the notification. Our app was initially written by an outside consulting company, so I'm not sure what they named the app originally. Is there a way to find this out? I've tried both the project name and the app name and neither works.

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259482/app-not-opened-when-clicking-on-message-in-notification-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my explanation in my in answer to following question. It also provides a solution: [App not opened when clicking on message in notification area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259482/app-not-opened-when-clicking-on-message-in-notification-area)

---

Copy/paste of the relevant text:

The `app_name` value in res\values\strings.xml is used internally to create Intent objects. So when the app is closed and the GCMIntentService receives a message, it creates an intent with the action as `<packagename>.<app_name>` and send it to notification service to show the notification in the notifications bar.

This is the intent name as used in AndroidManifest.xml to indicate that app has to be launched on tapping the notification:

```
<activity android:name=".PushNotifications" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="sensor"> 
    ....
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.PushNotifications.PushNotifications.NOTIFICATION"/>  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
    </intent-filter>
```

So now if the `app_name` is changed to any other string, internally the Intent will be created as `com.PushNotifications.<new_name>`.
But the AndroidManifest.xml still has for example `com.PushNotifications.PushNotifications` (in the case of the sample application), so the app is not getting launched as the intent action is different.

To display the application with a different name, follow these steps:

1. In strings.xml, add an additional  new_name_value
2. In AndroidManifest.xml , modify the label with the new string name

   ```
   <application android:label="@string/app_new_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon"> 
   <activity android:name=".PushNotifications" android:label="@string/app_new_name"...
   ```

Comment: I got it to work finally. It was actually a combination of a couple of things. The first was the changing of the app_name in the strings.xml file. Your answer above was the big piece of the puzzle though.  When I looked in the manifest file, the package name it was trying to use for the action was incorrect. It was missing a part of the package name in the string. I added the missing part, plus renaming the app back to its original value, and the app now launches when tapping the notification. Thanks for your help Idan.